# How to tag translation questions and questions concerning other languages

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags, retagging

We have tags "translation" and "english-to-russian". They now cover the same questions, and it's not good.

What do you think we should do about it?

Comment: I support it. It would be nice if you split the post into the question and the proposed answer, so that people can vote for it or propose their own ones.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that

1. we keep "translation" for questions like "How do you say X in Russian";
2. we remove "english-to-russian";
3. we add tags such as "English", "German", "French", "Spanish" and so on specifically for questions that involve other languages. They would cover not only the cases of translating language-specific words into Russian (such as "How do you write West-End: "Уэст-Энд" or "Вест-Энд"), but also all kind of special loanwords from these languages, similarity in syntax, and so on.

Please vote to say if you like this suggestion or not.

Comment: For per-language tags, that's what we do on [french.se]. A tag like [tag:german] basically means “you are more likely to be interested in this question if you speak German”. On the other hand, we use [tag:translation] in both directions, in principle only when the question is in principle about translation. “How do you say X in Russian” isn't really a translation question, it's a question about how to say something in Russian and is best tagged according to what the difficulty is (a vocabulary domain, a point of grammar, …).